# In C - Variable Incremented Inside a Loop Does Not Retain Value CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to C and have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string s = get_string("Enter string: ");
    int measure = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s);i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(s[i])==0)
        {
            measure++;
        }

    }
    printf("Measure is now %i\n", measure);
}
```

If I place my printf inside of the loop I can see measure incrimenting correctly, but it returns to zero when I have my printf after the loop is complete. I believe this is a scope problem, but my understanding is that a variable, in this case measure, declared outside of the loop has a scope of the main function and so can be modified in for and while loops. I'm thinking this is wrong and I am not sure how to get a value in the scope of a loop passed back to the main function.

Edit: I'm leaving this post as it was originally so the comments below make sense. @MaroBonelli led me to notice that I got confused between two windows and a printf inside of the loop in this code did not actually print the values.

Comment: What you're saying does not make sense. The value will not magically reset to 0 if you don't explicitly reset it somehow. If you meant to count alphabetic characters then the check `if (isalpha(s[i]) == 0)` is wrong, it should be the exact opposite: `if (isalpha(s[i]))`.

Comment: Your posted code does not display the behavior. `measure` will be incremented. I suspect in your actual code, `measure` is *shadowed* by being declared in two different scopes. Add `-Wshadow` to your compile string (gcc/clang) of `/W3` (VS/`cl.exe`) and see if any warnings are issued.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli good catch on `isalpha(s[i])==0` -- blew right past that.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes you are correct. I was working out of two windows and had my printf in a loop with just if(isalpha(s[i]) and the printf outside the loop I had if(isalpha(s[i])==0). As a side question, I thought that if(isalpha(s[i]) would be equivalent to if (isalpha(s[i])==1) but this does not seem to be the case. Wouldn't both check for a bool value of true?

Comment: @Michael read the manual for the function (`man isalpha`): "*RETURN VALUE: The values returned are nonzero if the character c falls into the tested class, and zero if not.*". It only says the return value will be *non zero*, so you cannot assume any particular value beforehand. It could even be negative.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thank you for that. I'm still getting used to the man pages and some of their terminology is still pretty cryptic to me.I read that as 0 for false and 1 for true. When I change the code to if(isalpha(s[i])!=0) it works great. I know just if(isalpha(s[i]) is probably more syntactically correct, but while I'm learning I'm trying to be explicit in my code while I get my head around things. Please put your comment or something similar as an answer so I can mark it correct. Thank you again!

Comment: @Michael as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating my comment into an answer:

The value will NOT reset to 0 if you don't explicitly reset it somehow. If you meant to count alphabetic characters then this check is wrong:

```
if (isalpha(s[i]) == 0)
```

It should be the exact opposite:

```
if (isalpha(s[i]))
// or
if (isalpha(s[i]) != 0)
```

From the manual page for `isalpha`:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> The values returned are nonzero if the character c falls into the tested class, and zero if not.